# Error while trying to run juju bootstrap

Tags: juju, maas

I was following the general how-to-install MAAS and after my nodes were successfully created, I went further to install juju to make openstack installation easy but then I get the following error:

```
 root@mymaas:/home/user# juju status 2013-02-18 19:52:46,361 INFO Connecting to environment... 
 Unhandled error in Deferred: Unhandled
 Error Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line
 545, in _runCallbacks
     current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 250,
 in _checkTimeout
     userDeferred.callback(result)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line
 362, in callback
     self._startRunCallbacks(result)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line
 458, in _startRunCallbacks
     self._runCallbacks()
 --- <exception caught here> ---   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line
 545, in _runCallbacks
     current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 369,
 in _setRealAddress
     self.doConnect()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 395,
 in doConnect
     connectResult = self.socket.connect_ex(self.realAddress)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) exceptions.TypeError: an integer is required 2013-02-18 19:53:16,380 ERROR Cannot connect to
 environment: Unexpected TimeoutError interacting with provider: User
 timeout caused connection failure. Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File
 "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/providers/common/connect.py",
 line 42, in run
     client = yield self._internal_connect(share) ProviderInteractionError: Unexpected TimeoutError interacting with
 provider: User timeout caused connection failure. Unexpected
 TimeoutError interacting with provider: User timeout caused connection
 failure. 2013-02-18 19:53:16,390 ERROR Unexpected TimeoutError
 interacting with provider: User timeout caused connection failure.
```

I don't know where I went wrong in the juju installation but below is what I have in my environment config file.

```
juju: environments 
  environments:
    maas:
     type: maas
     maas-server: 'http://{my-ip-address}/MAAS'
     maas-oauth: '${DXSKFbuHn3URhbCdD6:Z9V47vmsS2jDbxL4L2:6dQarDXcGuTZ7nvYemHMAnt2yHnUBRr2}'
     admin-secret: 'nothing'
     default-series: precise
```

Please help!

Comment: I fixed the initial problem I posted after poking around a few juju documentations. The next question is, when I run the bootstrap to load up my nodes, it shows an error when probing the first node. Unfortunately I can't paste the error message because I'm not home at the moment. But has anyone come across such error when running bootstrap, you get an error for the first node, and it stays there in loop?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this problem. I had to re-install juju with ppa:juju/pkgs, then removed `${}` wrapped around my maas-oauth API-key. I successfully run bootstrap.